# POCO C++ object to JSON string serialization

Tags: c++, json, serialization, poco

I wonder how could I serialize an object of a given class (e.g. Person) with its attributes (e.g. name, age) to a JSON string using POCO C++ libraries.

Maybe I should create my models using Poco::Dynamic and Poco::Dynamic::Var in order to use POCO::JSON::Stringifier? I can't imagine how to do this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you tell what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I didn't tried any approach so far, the only thing I've tried is to have a Resource Builder which "constructs" the final JSON using different helpers... but I would like something more "automatic" like C#'s library Newtonsoft for serialize/deserialize objects easily...

Comment: Are you dead set on POCO? There are other C++ libraries that are easier to use. https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example1.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Java or C#, C++ doesn't have an introspection/reflection feature outside of Run-time type information (RTTI), which has a different focus and is limited to polymorphic objects. That means outside of a non-standard pre-compiler, you'll have to tell the serialisation framework one way or another how your object is structured and how you would eventually like to map it to a hierarchy of `int`, `std::string` and other basic data types. I usually differentiate between three different approaches to do so: pre-compiler, inline specification, property conversion.

1. Pre-compiler: A good example of the pre-compiler approach is Google Protocol Buffers: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial. You define your entities in a separate `.proto` file, which is transformed using a proprietary compiler to `.c` and `.h` entity classes. These classes can be used like regular POCO entities and can be serialised using Protocol Buffers.
2. Inline specification: Boost serialization (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), s11n (www.s11n.net) and restc-cpp (https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp) are examples of explicitly specifying the structure of your POCOs for the framework inside your own code. The API to do so may be more or less sophisticated, but the principle behind it is always the same: You provide the framework `serialise`/`deserialise` implementations for your classes or you register metadata information which allows the framework to generate them. The example below is from restc-cpp:

```c++
struct Post {
    int userId = 0;
    int id = 0;
    string title;
    string body;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Post,
    (int, userId)
    (int, id)
    (string, title)
    (string, body)
)
```

3. Property conversion: The last kind of serialisation that I don't want to miss mentioning is the explicit conversion to a framework-provided intermediate data type. Boost property tree (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) and JsonCpp (http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/index.html) are good examples of this approach. You are responsible for implementing a conversion from your own types to `ptree`, which Boost can serialise to and from any format you like (XML, JSON).

Having had my share of experience with all three approaches in C++, I would recommend option 3 as your default. It seems to map nicely to POCO C++'s `Parser` and `Var` model for JSON. One option is to have all your entity POCO classes implement a `to_var` or `from_var` function, or you can keep these serialisation functions in a different namespace for each POCO class, so that you only have to include them when necessary.

If you are working on projects with a significant number of objects to serialise (e.g. messages in communication libraries), the pre-compiler option may be worth the initial setup effort and additional build complexity, but that depends, as always, on the specific project you're dealing with.

Comment: Hello and thanks Pascal, I need to be attached as requirement to POCO C++ framework (the community edition, not the pro). I know there are other libraries, if there is no change using POCO C++ then I should think seriously in those options. So the the third option using some generic methods (to_var, from_var) sounds interesting.

Comment: Hi Pablo, my personal recommendation would be using option 3 with POCO's `Var` data type anyway. However, you'll always have the option to convert to and from JSON strings using another library, and just send/receive these raw strings using the POCO framework, ignoring POCO's own JSON capabilities.

However, I'm not sure whether it's worth including additional libraries when POCO itself already has these parsers, hence my recommendation for option 3.